# Powershell WPF update on Event

Tags: wpf, powershell, event-handling

I'm having trouble updating my WPF-Window-Forms.
Basically, I want to trigger different content in my "Console-TextBox" depending on the current connected Network-SSID.

```
    [xml]$xaml = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\Pattern.xaml
    $manager = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager -ArgumentList $xaml.NameTable
    $manager.AddNamespace("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
    $xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml
    [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
}
$window = Load-Xaml

$textbox = $window.FindName("textbox")
$textbox_console = $window.FindName("textbox_console")
Get-EventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier 'MyEvent' -Action {$textbox_console.Text += "ManualInput"}


$networkChange = [System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange];
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $networkChange -EventName NetworkAddressChanged -SourceIdentifier NetworkChanged -Action {
    $textbox_console.Text += "`nNetworkChanged"
}

$textbox.Add_TextChanged({
    
    New-Event -SourceIdentifier 'MyEvent'
})

$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

XAML:

```
<Window
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="Pattern" Width="600" Height="400" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize"  
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="124,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textbox_console" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="70" Margin="124,104,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="console" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="262"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I'm new to Event Handling and not sure whether this issue is caused by Thread/Process-handling or wrong EventHandling...

Maybe somebody could point out some hint and tell me, how to use the NetworkChange-Event to update the text of the textbox?

Comment: Have you confirmed that event gets raised as expected? What happens?

Comment: The event get's definatelly raised, after doing sth on the form (either triggering textChanged by typing or pressing a button) the content get's updates the right way.

Comment: The Event gets raised but is Not actually updating the WPF UI @mm8